# Entity Framework Add-Migration Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is weird, when I use `Add-Migration` this error comes:

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\Alvin CMS Project\Custom
>   Plugins\EAccounting\EAccounting\bin\App_Data\log\error_log.txt'.

My error_log.txt is in my `'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\Alvin CMS Project\Custom Plugins\EAccounting\EAccounting\App_Data\log\error_log.txt'`. I do not know why the code is searching my error_log.txt when adding migration.

How to fix this?

Comment: Your solution (at least the required projects) must build when you try to add a migration. Do you have compile errors when building, or not ?

Comment: Can you show us the full command you use to add a migration?